# How do I echo a backspace from php cli?

Tags: php, bash, command-line-interface

This question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16149/overwrite-previous-output-in-bash-instead-of-appending-it

Explains how to do a countdown as a bash script. I want to do the same thing, but I need to do it in PHP. Is there a way to echo a backspace?

e.g.

```
echo "Counting down 60\n";
sleep(1);
echo "\b\b\b59\n";
sleep(1);
echo "\b\b\b58\n";
```

But, echo "\b" doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [Strings - Double quoted](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), there is no `\b` recognized as an escape sequence. You can use the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) backspace hex or octal code

```
$bs = "\x08";
echo "Counting down 60";
sleep(1);
echo "$bs$bs59";
sleep(1);
echo "$bs$bs58";
```

or in a loop all the way down to zero

```
$bs = "\x08";
for ($i = 59; $i >= 0; --$i) {
    sleep(1);
    printf("$bs$bs%2d", $i);
}
```

You must omit the newline `\n` as well.

Comment: Seriously? PHP has an escape sequence for a vertical tab `\v` but not a backspace `\b`? So much for making transitions from any `C`-like easier by having similar escape sequences...

Answer (score 9):

The backspace character corresponds to the ASCII character code 8, so you can output it using PHP's [`char()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function.

Ex. if you do something like:

```
echo 'Hello, world!' . chr(8);
```

The resulting output is:

```
Hello, world
```

Comment: I guess I should clarify that this is only really useful if you're working in a command-line context. If you're trying to just display a modified string to someone, you're probably better off just modifying it using a normal string function like [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) or something similar.